# Send event with different argument-types

Tags: c#, events, mono, event-handling

I've got a custom event containing data as `short[]`. There is also a type of this event using float[] instead but I don't know what is the smartest way to accomplish this without defining another `delegate`, `event` and of course `observer`. Ideally I'd like to have one observer-function which may evaluate both the short-array and float-array.

**How can I set this up?**

Here are delegate and event:

```
public delegate void SerialDataParseEventHandler (short[] packets, byte checksum);
public static event SerialDataParseEventHandler SerialDataParseEvent;
```

Here's how I send the event:

```
if (SerialDataParseEvent != null) {
    SerialDataParseEvent (packets, checksum);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define the parameter array as object, and check for type in the method.
see if that works.

Comment: When invoking SerialDataParseEvent I get `cannot convert short[] expression to type object[]`

Comment: `public delegate void SerialDataParseEventHandler (object[] packets, byte checksum);
public static event SerialDataParseEventHandler SerialDataParseEvent;`

is that how you define it now?